# Can't get host migrated from godaddy to Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, recordset

I'm trying to move the domain and so far I set the nameservers in godaddy to be the same ones as from Route 53.

I'm wondering what I should set my A name to, should it be an IP? I used S3 to host my website and have A pointed at its alias.

I also have a cname pointing www.helpsaverosie.com to www.helpsaverosie.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

I followed the guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

[image]

I purchased the domain through Go daddy and it worked before migrateing to Route 53, which now the website cannot be found.

*EDIT For some reason even the s3 bucket with www. apended doesn't work

www.helpsaverosie.ca.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

*EDIT Godaddy images
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of my route 53 records for a s3 hosted website, these settings work. If you have the equivalent setup, then your problem might be at the godaddy end, not the r53 end.

[image]

Comment: ug. so what do i do if this is a godaddy issue?

Comment: make 100% sure that the nameserver records you setup in godaddy, match the nameserver records in route 53 as a start.

Comment: I did several times copy and pasted them twice to. I removed the period from the end though

Comment: Your site seems to work for me. Also, this websit is helpful in finding dns errors: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3ahelpsaverosie.ca&run=toolpage#

Comment: So the www exists but nothing exists for the naked domain. Why is this? I set it up properly in r53

Comment: Is your problem that helpsaverosie.ca works and www.helpsaverosie.ca doesn't work?

Comment: clearing your chrome dns cache: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2F203674%2Fhow-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome&ei=LhssU6n8IsjgyQGwyYCgBw&usg=AFQjCNHYSeCQOqIIdb_vcLLPnIwWdgeVSQ&sig2=BADyXzwztZByep9Gop0BcQ&bvm=bv.62922401,d.aWc

Comment: This is strange I tried on my ipad phone and pc and none were working

Comment: well I don't think you are having godaddy or route53 issues, because both sites come up for me. You may just need to wait for the dns to be propagated everywhere.

Comment: Yes Indeed it seems to work when i Browser screenshot it using other sites just not locally for me. Its been like this for a few hours so I was getting worried but I'll wait longer thanks for helping me with this!

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are seetting the Route 53 nameservers inside your domain records. That is fine if you want to set them for a sub domain but not for the main domain. For the main domain you need to follow their instructions:

> If your domain name is registered with us, use the following instructions to set custom name servers for it.
>
> To Set Custom Nameservers for a Domain Name Registered with Us
>
> Log in to your Account Manager.
>
> Next to Domains, click Launch.
>
> Select the domain name(s) you want to modify.
>
> **From the Nameservers menu, select Set Nameservers.**
>
> Under Setup type, select Custom.
>
> Select Add Nameservers.
>
> Enter the two nameservers your hosting provider gave you.
>
> Click Add Nameserver if you have more than two nameservers.
>
> Click Save.

Here's the link: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names

Comment: Yeah that's what I saw but it looks like the name servers are in your domain records it's my understanding that they should not be there. They should be outside.

Comment: I have them outside and inside

Comment: Just outside. No need to be inside.

Comment: Ok zonefile for godaddy is empty now. Ill update back in an half hour with results

Comment: So I'm still getting a DNS lookup failed when trying to access the website

Comment: @Snowfiring I am having the same issue. Just wondering, did you ever got it to work? In my case, I have only updated the NS settings in godaddy. So the A record points to an IP address that shows the "parked domain" page. If i remove that A record, there is a "no lookup". I believe the issue lies in A record setting.